# round to significant number of digits in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, to-char

Is it possible to round a `double precision` number to a given number of significant digits in postgres?

I would like to reproduce the R function `signif` as closely as possible. In particular, I would like the result to conform to the IEEE 754 floating point standard for the format and rounding rules.

It looks like it may be possible using `to_char`: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-formatting.html

Here is the logic for R's `signif`: https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/b156e3a711967f58131e23c1b1dc1ea90e2f0c43/src/nmath/fprec.c

Comment: Is this what you are suggesting, https://www.garysieling.com/blog/postgres-significant-figures-pg_size_pretty?  Consider rounding 1.2345e-20 to 2 significant digits. In R signif(1.2345, 2) gives 1.2e-20 as expected. But following their example, select FLOOR(1.2345e-20 / (10 ^ FLOOR(log(1.2345e-20)-1))) * (10 ^ FLOOR(log(1.2345e-20)-1)); gives ERROR:  division by zero.

Comment: `round(x*power(10, sd-1-floor(log(abs(x))))) / power(10, sd-1-floor(log(abs(x))))` where `x` is your number and `sd` is significant digits.

Comment: select round(x,cast(-floor(log(abs(x))) as integer)) is a lot shorter for the most significant digit, be careful about zero